# jQuery load executes but callback is not executed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am kinda new to website development, so I am asking for some help on the matter. I have the following snippet of `html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <!--CSS Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/styles.css"/>

    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Navigation bar-->
        <div id="nav-placeholder"></div>
        <!--end of Navigation bar-->
    </body>

    <script src="../assets/js/navigation_bar.js" type="text/javascript", locator="about"></script>
</html>
```

It calls the `navigation_bar.js` script provided here

```js
locator = document.currentScript.getAttribute('locator');

function changeActiveElement(element_id){
    console.log("Called");
    nav_element = document.getElementById("navigation");
    for (i = 0; i < nav_element.length; i++) {
        console.log(nav_element[i].id)
        if(nav_element[i].id == element_id) document.getElementById(element_id).className = "active-nav-link";
        else document.getElementById(element_id).className = "nav-link";
    }
}

$(function()
    {$("#nav-placeholder").load("/assets/html/nav.html", function(){
        changeActiveElement(locator);
    });}
);
```

whereas the `nav.html` file is here:

```html
<nav>
    <h1><a href="index.html" class="nav-link-home">Some name</a></h1>
    <ul id="navigation" class="navigation">
      <li><a id="about" href="/pages/about.html" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
      <li><a id="compt" href="#compt" class="nav-link">Competences</a></li>
      <li><a id="projects" href="#projects" class="nav-link">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a id="contact" href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <button class="burger-menu" id="burger-menu">
      <ion-icon class="bars" name="menu-outline"></ion-icon>
    </button>
</nav>
```

The scope of the snippet is to change the class of the `a` tags listed in the `navigation` element. The navigation bar is correctly loaded via `$("#nav-placeholder").load("/assets/html/nav.html")`, yet `changeActiveElement` function is never executed via the callback.

Can someone explain me this behaviour?

Comment: It seems to me that instead of `$(function(){` you should be using `$( document ).ready(function() {`

Comment: @Zak incorrect. Please read https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @Zak [The former is shorthand for the latter](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and everything is working except that `nav_element` is not a list and therefore `nav_element.length` throws an error. You could use `document.querySelectorAll("#navigation");` instead, which returns a node list of all selected elements. Although, I would not recommend doing a for loop on elements by id. Use classes to select the elements. Id is only for one element.

Comment: Strangely enough I don't receive an output from the console by the `console.log` function in `changeActiveElement`. Anyway, my idea was not to iterate over multiple elements with id `navigation`, but rather navigate all the `li` elements of `ul` in the `nav.html`

Comment: I pasted your exact code into the three files and it is logging the "Called". Maybe you have something wrong elsewhere?